# Delete email on Logout

Tags: php, database

Like the title says how do i delete email when user logs out. I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];

     $sql = "DELETE FROM onlineusers WHERE email = $email";
     mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    session_destroy(); 

    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: That should be giving you query error. You have to wrap the email in quotes `... email = '$email'"`;`. **Huge BUT** here: look for **prepared statements** instead.

Comment: For reference: [**How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4577762)

Answer (score 0):

This should be your **query**

`$sql = "DELETE FROM onlineusers WHERE email = '$email'";`

> Note the `'$email'` instead of `$email`.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume that database connection is successful when you are on this script.
2. The only error I see is that $email needs to in single quotes as it might be of varchar type field in database.

   $sql = "DELETE FROM onlineusers WHERE email = '$email'";

Comment: I put $email in single quotes but it still doesn't work. Maybe if i explain what am i doing here will help. So when user logs in his email gets stored into onlineusers table in database and when he logs out his email gets deleted.

Comment: Did you check my first comment regarding connection to DB? You are using $link in mysqli_query, which I assume that your script is connecting with database.

Comment: Yes connection is fine.